# Vue.js transition on specific element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition

I have a ul with a bunch of li's. When you click on the li, it opens a menu page.

I'd like for the transition between the menu click and the new page loading to be a transition.

I have it set up like this:

|Menu.vue
|Edit.vue

Menu.vue:

```
<transition name="slide">
  <router-link to="/account/edit">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <i class="icon fa fa-users"></i>
      My Family
      <i class="right-arrow fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </li>
  </router-link>
</transition>
```

Menu.vue CSS

```
.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

And I have `transition: 'slide'` as a property of the Menu.vue instance.

This seems to bring this specific menu option in from the right. How can I make it so that when I click it the menu item, the transition occurs during the routing?

Comment: Note: Your `DOM` elements are out of order. a `router-link` converts to an `<a>` tag, so you have `<a><li></li></a>` which is not valid markup. Consider reordering that.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched that. Unfortunately it hasn't affected the transition or lack thereof